# Ambiguous Permutations Problem Code: PERMUT2(codechef)

Tags: c, algorithm

Checking For ambiguous permutation

INPUT:
The input contains several test cases.
The first line of each test case contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100000). Then a permutation of the integers 1 to n follows in the next line. There is exactly one space character between consecutive integers. You can assume that every integer between 1 and n appears exactly once in the permutation.
The last test case is followed by a zero.

OUTPUT:
For each test case output whether the permutation is ambiguous or not. Adhere to the format shown in the sample output.

My output is correct still the code is returning the wrong answer on submission. Not sure what is wrong.

```
int main(void) {
    int n, i, c, d;
    while(scanf("%d", &n), n!=0){
        c=0;
        int a[n];
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%ld", &a[i]);
        c=c*10+a[i];
        }
        i=n;
        int b[n];
        while(i>0){
            b[a[i-1]-1]=i;
            --i;
        }
        d=0;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            d=d*10+b[i];
        }
        c==d ? printf("ambiguous\n") : printf("not ambiguous\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%ld", &a[i]);` has the wrong type.

Comment: The code is missing `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Even after rectifying it, I'm getting the same error

Comment: What is an ambiguous permutation?

Comment: Please show some example input and the corresponding expected and actual output for both "ambiguous" and "non ambiguous" cases.

Comment: Btw look here https://ideone.com/aWGs6G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your thought process that the sum represented by permutation and sum represented by inverse permutation should be same, but this will not be true in all cases, as there might be some permutations for which both the sums are equal but they are not ambiguous.

A more simplistic and robust approach would be to check if **each element of permutation matches with inverse permutation or not**

Go through the following code, which has accepted status on Codechef:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, i;
    while(scanf("%d", &n), n!=0){

        int a[n];
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        i=n;
        int b[n];
        while(i>0){
            b[a[i-1]-1]=i;
            --i;
        }

        int flg = 1;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(a[i]!=b[i]){
                flg = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        (flg==1) ? printf("ambiguous\n") : printf("not ambiguous\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Kindly feel free to ask any doubts.